# What's the most efficient method for analyzing this non-Gaussian longitudinal count data in R?

Tags: r, time-series, lme4-nlme, panel-data

[image]
Experimental design: I have four treatment groups: control, early, late, both. For each group, I counted nymphs and eggs on leaves on five different dates. The design is randomized complete block design (four blocks per plot, each randomly assigned one of the treatments). A treatment was applied, which is suspected to reduce egg and nymph counts (vertical red dashed lines). For the early group, the treatment was applied on an early date. For the late group, the treatment was applied slightly later than the early group. For the both group, the early and late treatments were both applied.

I've never run stats on longitudinal data like this, so I'm unsure what the best approach is for analysis.

My response is count. I believe my fixed effects are: treatment, type (egg, nymph), and date. I believe my random effects are: block.

I would like to show that treatment does in fact reduce counts, relative to date-to-date baselines, and taking into account treatment date(s). Because my data is not normal, with some extreme outliers even when transformed, I don't think I can use an analysis that assumes normally distributed residuals.

I've read into GLMM, nlme, lme4, and anovaRMNP, but am completely clueless of how to structure my formulas to work with any of these.

Once I get started with one of these, I know how to produce additive and crossed models and how to compare them by AIC.

Comment: Is each treatment qualitatively different in each block, or is the only difference treatment *timing*? If the timing is the only difference, then is the “both” treatment condition akin to a double dose of treatment? Could you elaborate further?

Comment: Qualitatively the exact same, only different timing. The both treatment is akin to a double dose, on separate dates.

Comment: "non-Gaussian count data" is redundant. You should definitely look some more into GLMs (don't bother with the mixed-models part before you understand these). Start with Poisson regression.

Comment: I've worked with GLM's plenty, generally with negative binomial for overdispersed count data and probit for dose response. I'm just extremely unfamiliar with glmm. I've tried every possible glmmTMB distribution so far, and it's always throwing errors at me.

Comment: "throwing errors at me" is way too unspecific. Are these errors from the optimizer or the convergence checks? GLMMs are more challenging to optimize than LMMs. I've recently started working on a problem where I needed a Gamma GLMM with identity link and that was a nightmare of optimizer issues (Gamma GLMMs are [notorious](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#gamma-glmms) for this). My solution was to switch to Bayesian models (using the excellent rstanarm package).

Comment: Yeah it's the common convergence check errors. The troubleshotting vignette is another language to me. I'll keep working on it though

Comment: Also, one issue could be that the block effect might be small and you have a low number of blocks. Is that the case in your data?

Comment: I don't think so.. each of the 4 blocks contain 880 clustered counts

Comment: But you only have 4 blocks ... A random effect is just a parameter modelling a variance. You are basically trying to estimate a variance of a distribution based on 4 values. Now, I frequently work with a similar design (having only four blocks is common) and successfully use (G)LMMs for it but you need to be aware that this can be problematic. I've read recommendations that you should have at least 30 subjects for a random effect ...

Comment: Ah I see. I have 4 plots of 4 blocks so only 16 subjects. Should I consider it fixed then?

Comment: I can't say without studying the data and model in detail. I just need to say that you have a nested design: `| block / plot`. I would model this as a random effect if possible and I would hesitate to simply flatten this to `| block : plot`. However, that might be justified if there is very small variance between blocks.